# Migrating to flame v1.0.0

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

I'm Migrating to flame v1.0.0-rc8 from flame v0.29.4
and I can't find a good roadmap of how to get the `initialDimensions`, how to get the engine widget via `engine.widget`, how to init the `Sprite` object (Previously via `Sprite('path_to_asset_file')`), and how to set the width and height for `SpriteComponent` (Previously via `SpriteComponent.rectangle`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are several questions, so I'll give several answers:

1. How to get the `inititialDimensions`?

`inititialDimensions` is no longer needed, `onGameResize` is called before `onLoad` which will give you the size of the game. You can also get the size of the game by adding the `HasGameRef` mixin to your `Component`s and call `gameRef.size`.

2. How to get the flutter widget?

You now wrap your game inside of a `GameWidget` instead of using `.widget`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';

void main() {
  final myGame = MyGame();
  runApp(
    GameWidget(
      game: myGame,
    ),
  );
}
```

3. How to initialize a `Sprite`?

You usually want a `SpriteComponent`, and not a raw `Sprite`.

To create a `Sprite`:

```dart
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  Sprite player;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    player = Sprite.load('player.png');
  }
}
```

To create a `SpriteComponent`:

```dart
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  SpriteComponent player;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final sprite = await loadSprite('player.png');
    player = SpriteComponent(sprite: sprite);
    // And you usually want to add your component to the game too.
    add(player);
  }
}
```

4. How to set the size of a component?

Simply do `component.size = Vector2(width, height);` or `component.width = width;` + `component.height = height`

Comment: How can I get the `size` directly?

Comment: @AliHabbash so in v1 you should do all your initialization in `onLoad` on your game and `onLoad` on your component, in the `onLoad` method on your game there is a `size` variable which is initialized that you can use directly and the same for your components, but there the variable is called `gameSize`.